# Python read specific data table

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i'm working on is something like this:

cell  21
 multiplier:   1.02400E+00    3        103
         time

```
5.0000E+02   7.08884E-06 0.0008
1.0600E+03   3.77034E-06 0.0027
1.6900E+03   3.37108E-06 0.0039
2.4000E+03   3.31327E-06 0.0048
3.1900E+03   3.36657E-06 0.0056
4.0800E+03   3.51381E-06 0.0062
5.0800E+03   3.66066E-06 0.0067
6.1900E+03   3.74282E-06 0.0072  --- i need this data from here to
7.4300E+03   3.80566E-06 0.0077
8.8400E+03   3.96633E-06 0.0080
1.0400E+04   3.95870E-06 0.0085
1.2200E+04   4.25023E-06 0.0087
1.4100E+04   3.85369E-06 0.0096
1.6400E+04   4.04088E-06 0.0098
1.8900E+04   3.34150E-06 0.0112
2.1700E+04   2.66266E-06 0.0128  
2.4900E+04   1.82856E-06 0.0160
2.8500E+04   1.03725E-06 0.0211
3.2500E+04   4.73739E-07 0.0314
3.7000E+04   2.27247E-07 0.0450
4.2100E+04   1.19012E-07 0.0670
4.7800E+04   6.49180E-08 0.0876
5.4200E+04   2.54971E-08 0.1302
6.1400E+04   1.69030E-08 0.1829
6.9500E+04   7.24287E-09 0.2489
7.8700E+04   7.15292E-09 0.2794
8.8900E+04   1.81884E-09 0.5471
1.0100E+05   8.62254E-10 0.6012
1.1300E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.2800E+05   9.05231E-10 0.7085
1.4400E+05   4.06689E-10 1.0000
1.6300E+05   9.77137E-11 1.0000
1.8300E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.0700E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.3300E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.6300E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.9600E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000 ------here
3.3300E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
3.7600E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
4.2300E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
4.7600E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
5.3600E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
6.0400E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
6.8000E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
7.6500E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
8.6100E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
9.6900E+05   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.0900E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.2200E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.3800E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.5500E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.7500E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.9700E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.2100E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.5000E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
2.8000E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
3.1500E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
3.5400E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
3.9900E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
4.4900E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
5.0500E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
5.6800E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
6.3900E+06   0.00000E+00 0.0000
1.0000E+07   0.00000E+00 0.0000
  total      6.55186E-05 0.0019
```

also i need to add the numbers like 3.74282E-06 + 3.80566E-06 + 3.96633E-06+ ....0.00000E+00 = 3.74E-05

please help me to fine out how to do it :((

Comment: Have you written any code yet?

Comment: What exactly is your criteria for "from here to here"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using NumPy or equivalent is doing it by hand. Since it's such a simple task, it might be educational to do so. Assuming it's in a normal text file, you can use something like this:

```
dataList = []
with open("data.dat") as f:
    dataList = [tuple(line.split()) for line in f]
```

Of course, you'd need logic to determine what records you want to include. Note that this will be a list of tuples of strings, not of true numbers. For adding the numbers together like you mentioned, consider using `float` like so:

```
num = sum([float(i[1]) for i in dataList])
```

The above code will sum all the elements of the second column in the table.

Comment: Let's not consider `eval` for adding the numbers when passing it to `float` will work, and correctly error if not convertable to a float, rather than potentially do all sorts of weird things...

Comment: Good call. The given exponent format surprised me and I jumped to the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('yourFile.csv','rb'))
nparray = np.array(list(reader))

selected = nparray[8:37]
sum = np.sum(selected[:,1])

print selected
print sum
```

Though if this is really what you wanted, a simple google search would have gotten you far. NumPy is also optional.. a counter in a loop or csv's line_num would have also done the same.